# Reversing a doubly linked list with Header Node

Tags: c, list, linked-list

The objective is to reverse a doubly linked list containing words with a header node. I have used the standard algorithm where I reverse the left and right links of the individual nodes of the Linked list.

Here is the code that I have written

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char data[10];
    struct node *rlink;
    struct node *llink;
}NODE;

NODE* insert(NODE *header,char info[])
{
    NODE *new,*temp;
    temp=header;
    new=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(new->data,info);
    new->rlink=NULL;
    new->llink=NULL; 
    while(temp->rlink!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->rlink;
    }
    temp->rlink=new;
    new->llink=temp;
    new->rlink=NULL;
    header->llink=NULL;
    return header;
}

void display(NODE *header)
{
    NODE *temp=header->rlink;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \t",temp->data);
        temp=temp->rlink;
    }
}

void displayr(NODE *header)
{
    NODE *temp=header->rlink;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s \t",temp->data);
        temp=temp->rlink;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int num,i=0;
    char info[10];
    NODE *header;
    header=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    header->rlink=NULL;
    header->llink=NULL;
    printf("\n Enter the number of strings \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",info);
        header=insert(header,info);
    }
    printf("\n Displaying the original linked list");
    display(header);
    NODE *temp1=header;
    NODE *temp2;
    while(temp1->rlink!=NULL) //Reversing the linked list
    {
        temp2=temp1->rlink;
        temp1->rlink=temp1->llink;
        temp1->llink=temp2;
        temp1=temp2;
    }
    temp1->rlink=temp1->llink;
    temp1->llink=NULL;
    printf("\n Displaying reverse \n");
    display(header);
}
```

The problem is that it's not displaying the reversed linked list.

For instance, if my input is `why so serious`, I have no output at all.

Comment: You will attract better answers if you structure your question differently. For example, include only the relevant bits, make them short ('this is the working part') and then show the non-working part. Include your understanding or the lack of understanding.

Comment: I just want to know the reason to reverse doubly linked list. As you are having a doubly linked list just make your last node as your start node and you are done. There is no need to play with links between nodes in case of a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code

1. The size of your linked list is one more than the number of items entered by the user.
2. The first node of your list is empty(contains) no data.
3. To compunsate of this, your display function starts printing from the second node of the list.

Now coming to the actual question that you asked: Why is the reversed linked list not displayed

So the issue is with the *header*. Originally, it was pointing to the start of the list. So, when you exchanged the right and the left pointers, the *header* is technically now pointing to the last node of the list. Your new header becomes *temp1*. *temp1* stores the address of the node on the right of which the list is present hence it plays the role of the header.

```
printf("\n Displaying reverse \n");
display(temp1);
```

Now this will partially solve your problem because when you will call the function *display(temp1)* you will observe that one element of the list is missing. This is due to the problems i mentioned in the first part of my answer. The display function is written in such a manner that it will start printing the list from second node onwards. You can change it to :

```
void display(NODE *header)
{
    NODE *temp=header; //start from the first node itself
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \t",temp->data);
        temp=temp->rlink;
    }
}
```

But with this you must also change your insertion code to store first value in the header not and not keep the header value empty. In the current situation where the first node value if empty, the display function will print one extra tab space.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what Avantika Saini said, your data structure upon reading looks like

> 0<-h->why
>   h<-why->so
>   why<-so->serious
>   so<-serious->0
>
> where 0 is NULL
>   h is header
>   <- and -> are llink and rlink
>   otherwise the names represents nodes

After your reversal you have

> why<-h->0
>   so<-why->h
>   serious<-so->why
>   0<-serious->so

To fix your issues

- Initialize 'header' to NULL in main and do not allocate an empty NODE for it.
- Have `insert` check whether the input header is NULL. If it is just return the new NODE. Otherwise append to the end.
- Don't skip the first element in `display` or when traversing the list for the reversal.
- You have to make sure that at the end of the reversal `header` points to the end of the original list (the `serious` NODE).

After this your data structures should look like

> 0<-why[header]->so
>   why<-so->serious
>   so<-serious->0
>
> I've added [header] to show which NODE it points to

After your reversal you should have

> so<-why->0
>   serious<-so->why
>   0<-serious[header]->so

A couple of other pieces of advice:

Don't use `new` as a variable name. In fact, don't use any C++ keywords or library functions. If ever you have to integrate with or migrate to C++ this will avoid problems.

You don't free any of the memory. You need to traverse the list, freeing each NODE.